# TeXstudio not showing help tooltips when commands are hovered over

Tags: texstudio, tooltips

I have heard that TexStudio has help tooltips for certain common commands when you hover over them. Yet when I hover any command e.g \small, nothing is shown. Am I misinterpreting what is meant by help tooltip or is there something I need to enable?

I'm very new to LaTeX so thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you had a look at the manual? Maybe you need to [activate this feature](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040) first. Also, I guess, there will be tool tips only for certain macros.

Comment: Thank you! I am only using the built in commands for now and i believe that their completion files are being used if that was the feature you were refering to. I tried looking through the manual for anything on tooltips and didn't find anything. Are there any commands you know have hover-over tooltips that I can check myself?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue here. I tried all configuration options, I tried both under WIN 11 and under Ubuntu Linux, but behavior is the same: there's no way I can see help tooltips for any Latex commands in the editor. I am able to preview text as tooltip (right click, then Preview Selection), I am able to preview Images when hovering over with the mouse but nothing for LaTeX commands. Were you able to solve this issue? Thanks!